# How to call yourself in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microphone, microsoft-teams

How can I call myself in Microsoft Teams (possibly over the phone) in order to test some special sound device settings?

I know about the [Teams Echo Bot test call](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-your-call-settings-in-teams-456cb611-3477-496f-b31a-6ab752a7595f#:%7E:text=ones%20that%20ring.-,Make%20a%20test%20call,-To%20make%20a), which however is not sufficient for my purpose (specifically, the bot does not allow to test the echo that other participants may hear of themselves).

Comment: Perhaps by using "Meet now"?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't yet found a way to test my own echo myself, I have since asked various colleagues. They have denied hearing any echo of themselves through Teams, even though I use an extremely sensitive desktop microphone and desktop speakers instead of a headset.

So Teams is apparently very good at suppressing echo.

If the organization has enabled it, you can also [call yourself on a landline](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-dial-pad-to-make-a-call-20d24ace-2851-4c29-8441-30dd2a5cf078#:%7E:text=To%20dial%20a%20number%20from,or%20numbers%2C%20and%20click%20Call%20.) in the Teams sidebar under "Calls", and try whether an echo is generated.

Otherwise, you can at least [hold a meeting with yourself](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftTeams/comments/g1suhb/comment/fnhfjlv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and record your own audio (and video) this way. Doing so, I found that Teams also filters out loud keyboard noise almost completely, but only as long as you're not talking at the same time.

While you are talking, keyboard noise and other sounds such as rustling paper are transmitted almost unsuppressed.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to start a room using Slack (/teams), then join the room and test audio/video.  You can even record the meeting, then play it back to get a true sense of quality.

Of course, that requires Slack with Teams Integration setup.  But maybe you could do something similar with other IM clients?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After considerable frustration that Microsoft refuses to provide a way to do this, I realized you can do it by using 2 devices, using a different account on each device.  The following should work:

1. Create an instant meeting ("Meet Now")
2. Make a second account
3. Log into the second account on another device (e.g., your smartphone).  **Be sure to disable the mic before you connect to avoid feedback**.

The trick here is getting the meeting URL to your second device.  You could email or message it to yourself (not using Teams :-) ).

In order to hear the audio well, I connected headphones on my phone.  (This also dealt with a little remaining feedback.)

Comment: This works for all versions of Teams.  Of course, if you have a corporate account, you have more options.  For example, you can generate a dial-in number for a meeting, and call yourself on that.

Comment: I'm curious, why the downvote?  This is the only thing here that is a general answer.  Don't downvote answers because you're frustrated with Microsoft.  Microsoft's follies are their own fault.